# How to load json from file and set it as global variable in Vue?

Tags: json, vue.js

I'm new to Vue. I want to read `employeeId` from a login form and ust it to load some json files named according as employeeId.json like (10000001.json, 20000001.json) and set the json object as a global variable so I can easily access it in all components.

Firstly, I don't know how to dynamically load json files. Using `import` sees not work. Some one suggested using `require` should work. But there are not many examples, I don't know where to put require...

Secondly, how do I set the json as global after the employeeId props in? I'm very confused where to put it (inside the export default or not? inside methods or not? or inside created/mounted or not?) and where to use this or not...

This is the script section of my headerNav.vue file.

```
<script>
//**I placed them here now, it works, but employeeId is hard coded...
import json10000001 from "./json/10000001.json";
import json20000001 from "./json/20000001.json";
import json30000001 from "./json/30000001.json";
// var employeeId = employeeIdFromLogin;
var jsonForGlobal;
var employeeId = 10000001;
var jsonFileCurrentObj;
if (employeeId == "10000001") {
  jsonForGlobal = jsonFileCurrentObj = json10000001;
} else if (employeeId == "20000001") {
  jsonForGlobal = jsonFileCurrentObj = json20000001;
} else if (employeeId == "30000001") {
  jsonForGlobal = jsonFileCurrentObj = json30000001;
}

export default {
  // props:{
  //   employeeIdFromLogin: String,
  // },
  props:['employeeIdFromLogin'],
  jsonForGlobal,
  // employeeIdFromLogin,
  data() {
    return {
      docked: false,
      open: false,
      position: "left",
      userinfo: {},
      jsonFileCurrent: jsonFileCurrentObj,
      // employeeIdFromLogin: this.GLOBAL3.employeeIdFromLogin
      // jsonFile: currentJsonFile
    };
  },
  mounted() {
//**I tried put it here, not working well...
    // var employeeId = this.employeeIdFromLogin;
    // // var jsonForGlobal;
    // console.log("headernav.employeeIdFromLogin="+this.employeeIdFromLogin);
    // // var employeeId = 10000001;
    // var jsonFileCurrentObj;
    // if (employeeId == "10000001") {
    //   this.jsonForGlobal = this.jsonFileCurrentObj = json10000001;
    // } else if (employeeId == "20000001") {
    //   this.jsonForGlobal = this.jsonFileCurrentObj = json20000001;
    // } else if (employeeId == "30000001") {
    //   this.jsonForGlobal = this.jsonFileCurrentObj = json30000001;
    // }
  },
  methods: {
    switchPage(pageName) {
      this.$emit("switchPage", pageName);
    }
//**I don't know how to use the require...
    // var employeeId = 10000001;
    // getJsonFile(employeeId) {
    //   this.currentJsonFile = require("../assets/json/" + employeeId + ".json");
    // }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use vuex to manage global store. But if you don't want includes Vuex, there is a simpler way to have global state:

Define globalStore.js

```
// globalStore.js
export const globalStore = new Vue({
  data: {
    jsonForGlobal: null
  }
})
```

then import it and use in component:

```
import {globalStore} from './globalStore.js'
export default {
  props: ['employeeIdFromLogin'],
  data: function () 
    return {
      jsonLocal: globalStore.jsonForGlobal,
      jsonFileCurrent: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    employeeIdFromLogin: {
      handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        const data = require('./json/' + this.employeeIdFromLogin + '.json')
        this.jsonFileCurrent = data
        globalStore.jsonForGlobal = data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I'm trying... Now it shows an error, possibly the headerNav.vue is loaded even on the login page (which it should not be)... I'm checking vue router to fix... ``` TypeError: Cannot read property 'employeeName' of null
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js...```

Comment: Hi, I'm still struggling on using this... Still haven't succeed. I'm a bit of confused, is this should be placed in every components? And what should be in the login.vue?...